# Capture focused html element value from web page Opened in chrome browser

Tags: c#

I am working to capture web page control, web page is opened in chrome browser.

I am using System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement. My c# code is as below.

```
static void Main()            
{
   Automation.AddAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler(OnFocusChangedHandler);
}
static void OnFocusChangedHandler(object src, AutomationFocusChangedEventArgs args)
{   
    AutomationElement element = src as AutomationElement;
    if (element != null)
    {
        string name = element.Current.Name;
        string value = element.GetText();       
        if (value != string.Empty)
        {
            using (Process process = Process.GetProcessById(processId))
            {
                if (process.ProcessName != null && process.ProcessName.Contains("chrome"))
                {                   
                    Console.WriteLine("  Name: {0},Value: {1}", name, value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public static class AutomationExtensions
    {
        public static string GetText(this AutomationElement element)
        {
            object patternObj;
            if (element.TryGetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern, out patternObj))
            {
                var valuePattern = (ValuePattern)patternObj;
                return valuePattern.Current.Value;
            }
            else if (element.TryGetCurrentPattern(TextPattern.Pattern, out patternObj))
            {
                var textPattern = (TextPattern)patternObj;
                return textPattern.DocumentRange.GetText(-1).TrimEnd('\r'); // often there is an extra '\r' hanging off the end.
            }
            else
            {
                return element.Current.Name;
            }
        }
    }
```

I got browser URL value when user change focus from address bar.

I want to capture html element values.Right now I am getting following.

"Name: Chrome Legacy Window,Value: Chrome Legacy Window "

please help me.

NOTE:
Type "chrome://accessibility/" in address bar and set accessible to true for web site allows to capture values.

I need to capture without setting accessibility attribute, as it is impossible to set flag.

Comment: System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement is not powerful enough to capture html elements inside browser. It is meant to capture elements on your OS. I would recommend Selenium to fulfill your need.

Comment: Thanks for reply. We are not allowed to install any thing on target machine.

Comment: why dont you use javascript focus on html please see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_html_focus_onload

Comment: HI TAHATEMURII, I want to get every html element that user is accessing. From outside of the browser. The capture application is running in background.